# Launch 3rd party app without status bar or notification bar? Android

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar

How can I launch a 3rd party app but disable the top tool bar? I have seen this in child tablets, where any attempt as swiping down on the top toolbar does not work. The toolbar is either locked, removed, or opens but immediately closes.

Again, this is while a 3rd party app is running. Not while inside my own app. I am unaware of how to make this happen. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that's impossible.

Comment: But Ive seen this done. Most tablets for children have this feature, where they launch a 3rd party app and they cannot access the status bar. Is this special arrangement possibly between the apps preloaded on the device?